# C# VScrollBar value not correct

Tags: c#

I have a C# VScrollBar in a form with maximum value 29 and minimum to -29, my problem is when i run my program a use the VScrollbar and press up the negative number show and when I press down the positive number show , how do I make it positive numbers up and negative number down??? thank you

Comment: int thatIsWhatIWant = `-`VScrollBar.Value; (?)

Answer (score 1):

Can't get you question clearly.

At your `VscrollBar` properties explorer, set:

```
Value = -29 //This will give your scroll bar start at your min. position
```

Then, at your event:

```
private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = vScrollBar1.Value; //Check your value here when you move your scroll bar
}
```